# Getting Usage Data + Charges Export of Azure Costs and Storing Information Inside a Azure Container

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to create an export of my Azure Usages and Charges into a CSV by setting the scope to my Billing Account ID in a PowerShell script. I've ran the code and it works, but when I do a cost generation in another PowerShell script it seems like the command isn't getting all of the charges. Checking the file sent to the Azure Container, I've found that it is roughly 641 MB in size and when I manually download the Usage + Charges.csv from the Azure Portal, the csv is 656 MB in size. That means that there is roughly 15 MB of data missing from the Billing Account Scope, and I was wondering if I have the right idea here by exporting the CSV via PowerShell.

My ultimate goal is to automate the csv export each month so I can email myself the costs in another PowerShell script. I have contacted Microsoft about the issue and will meet with them to discuss the problem, but I was wondering if anyone has done something similar in their own time and if they could automate the Usage + Charges.csv by themselves. The code is posted below and any tips or pointers would help out.

**Export Code:**

```
# Log into the Azure Subscription and authenticate the login
Az Login

# Set variables for the command. 
$subscriptionId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$storageAccountId = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$containerName = "publicstoragecontainer001"
$exportName = "Usage Data for XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$timeFrame = "TheLastBillingMonth"
$type = "Usage"
$folderName = "Total Usage Cost Exports"
$scheduleStatus = "Active"
$reoccurance = "Monthly"

# Get the Usage from the Billing Scope. 
$scope = "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

# Time Variables
$current_time = Get-Date
$future_time = $current_time.AddHours(1)
$current_time_str = $current_time.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
$future_time_str = $future_time.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")


# Export the usage data of each tenant to the storage account
az costmanagement export create --name $exportName --scope $scope --storage-account-id $storageAccountId --storage-container $containerName --timeframe $timeFrame --type $type --storage-directory $folderName --schedule-status $scheduleStatus --recurrence $reoccurance --recurrence-period from=$current_time_str to=$future_time_str
```

Comment: But does the total figure match? The size difference could be escape characters, quote delmiting etc.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Total figure matches for all except one cost center. I manually downloaded the Usage+Charges.csv from the Azure Portal and did a manual test of costs that way. When I downloaded the manual csv, the information was correct and accurately reflected the charges I used that month. When I pulled the Export from the Storage Container, one of my cost centers was off by a significant amount.

Comment: and when you drill into that cost centre can you identify any pattern on what is missing? There might be an inbuilt MS tool that already covers whatever you are trying to do at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the issue.**

The -type parameter needs to be set to ActualCost instead of Usage. if you set it to ActualCost, then the command will acquire both the Usage + Charges for the export csv instead of just the usage data. Changing the Parameter gets you the results you need.

Thank you to everyone who contributed!

## Log into the Azure Subscription and authenticate the login

Az Login

```
# Set variables for the command. 
$subscriptionId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$storageAccountId = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$containerName = "publicstoragecontainer001"
$exportName = "Usage Data for XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$timeFrame = "TheLastBillingMonth"
$type = "ActualCost"
$folderName = "Total Usage Cost Exports"
$scheduleStatus = "Active"
$reoccurance = "Monthly"

# Get the Usage from the Billing Scope. 
$scope = "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

# Time Variables
$current_time = Get-Date
$future_time = $current_time.AddHours(1)
$current_time_str = $current_time.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
$future_time_str = $future_time.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")


# Export the usage data of each tenant to the storage account
az costmanagement export create --name $exportName --scope $scope --storage-account-id $storageAccountId --storage-container $containerName --timeframe $timeFrame --type $type --storage-directory $folderName --schedule-status $scheduleStatus --recurrence $reoccurance --recurrence-period from=$current_time_str to=$future_time_str
```